# Enabling and disabling field validator for button click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have two button control. I want to disable the field validator for textboxes when I click `btnavail_Click`. Its working. But when I click the button `btnsubmit_Click` the field validator is not enabled.

```
 protected void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RequiredFieldValidator2.Enabled = true;
            RequiredFieldValidator3.Enabled = true;
            RequiredFieldValidator4.Enabled = true;
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblstudentinfo where StudentId=@studentid", con);
            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@studentid",txtstudentid.Text.ToString());
            SqlDataReader rdr=cmd1.ExecuteReader();
            if(rdr.Read())
            {
                int i=Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Password"]);
                int j=Convert.ToInt32(txtpassword.Text);
                if(i == j)
                {
                    SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select * from tblbookinfo where Name=@bookname", con);
                    cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookname", txtbookname.Text.ToString());
                    SqlDataReader rdr1 = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                    if (rdr1.Read())
                    {
                        int s = Convert.ToInt32(rdr1["BookId"]);
                        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("inserttotbllendinginfo2", con);
                        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
                        {
                            ParameterName = "@bookid",
                            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                            Value = s
                        });
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
                        {
                            ParameterName = "@studentid",
                            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                            Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtstudentid.Text)
                        });
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
                        {
                            ParameterName = "@noofbooks",
                            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int,
                            Value = Convert.ToInt32(txtnoofbook.Text)
                        });
                        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter
                        {
                            ParameterName = "@dateoflending",
                            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Date,
                            Value = txtdate.Text
                        });
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    }
                 }
                else
                {
                    lblpassword.Visible=true;
                    lblpassword.Text="Your password is incorrect. Please Check it";
                    lblpassword.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }

                con.Close();
              }
        }

        protected void btnavail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RequiredFieldValidator2.Enabled = false;
            RequiredFieldValidator3.Enabled = false;
            RequiredFieldValidator4.Enabled = false;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tblbookinfo where Name=@bookname", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@bookname", txtbookname.Text.ToString());
            con.Open();
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbookname.Text))
            {
                lblbookavail.Visible = true;
                lblbookavail.Text = "Please enter a valid book name";
                lblbookavail.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
            }
            else
            {
            SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();            
                if (rdr.Read())
                {
                    string s = rdr["Name"].ToString();
                    if (s != null)
                    {
                        int i = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["AvailableBooks"]);
                        lblbookavail.Visible = true;
                        lblbookavail.Text = (i.ToString());
                    }
            }
            }
           con.Close();
            }
```

I made causes validation property for both the buttons to false. I need to enable the validator when I click `btnsubmit_Click`. Please someone help me.

```
<table align="center">
            <tr><td>Book Name</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtbookname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Requires book name" ControlToValidate="txtbookname" ForeColor="Red" Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                <td><asp:Button ID="btnavail" runat="server" Text="Book Availability"   OnClick="btnavail_Click" /></td><td><asp:Label ID="lblbookavail" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Student Id</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtstudentid" runat="server" ValidationGroup="save"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Requires Studentid" ControlToValidate="txtstudentid" ForeColor="Red" Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td></tr>
            <tr><td>No of Book</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtnoofbook" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Requires no of book" ControlToValidate="txtnoofbook" ForeColor="Red" Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Date of lending</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtdate" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox></td></tr>
            <tr><td>Password</td><td><asp:TextBox ID="txtpassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server"  ></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Requires Studentid" ControlToValidate="txtpassword" ForeColor="Red" Text="*"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator></td>
                <td><asp:Label ID="lblpassword" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label></td></tr>
            <tr><td><asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit"  OnClick="btnsubmit_Click" /></td></tr>
            </table>
```

This my HTML code. I want to disable Field validator for studentid,no of books and password on btnavail_click. Again I need to enable them for btnsubmit_click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because, you are enabling your `RequiredFieldValidator` in server side code i.e. on button click event handler and validation controls like `RequiredFieldValidator` works on client side. This means when you click on `Submit` buttton, since your validator was disabled it didn't worked and form was posted to the server, now even if you enable the Validator now, its of no use since form is already posted.

Instead of Enabling & Disabling the validator controls, you should set the [CausesValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.causesvalidation(v=vs.110).aspx) property for each button control to either `true` or `false`, like this:-

```
<asp:Button ID="SubmitButton" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
            CausesValidation="true" OnClick="SubmitButton_Click" />
```

**Update:**

Since you don't want validation on `btnavail` button, set `CausesValidation="false"` for this button, your mark-up should look like:-

```
<asp:Button ID="btnavail" runat="server" Text="Book Availability" 
            CausesValidation="false" OnClick="btnavail_Click" />
```

Comment: I made Causes Validation for the btnsubmit_Click to true.It works when I double time cilck that button.

Comment: @MonaVaradharaju - You need to completely remove `RequiredFieldValidator2.Enabled` & `RequiredFieldValidator2.Disabled` code from code behind.

Comment: @MonaVaradharaju - What is not working? You mean when you don't enter anything in textbox and click on button, form is posting back to server? Have you cleared the Cache? Please check and let me know.

Comment: @RahulSingh- I attahed my HTML code. Can you please see that

Answer (score 1):

Why not add `ValidationGroup` to your textbox and button(btnsubmit) something like this

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" ValidationGroup="save"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" 
            ValidationGroup="save"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ValidationGroup="save"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
            ErrorMessage="RequiredFieldValidator" ControlToValidate="TextBox2" 
            ValidationGroup="save"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAvail" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="save" 
            onclick="btnAvail_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" Text="Button" 
            onclick="btnsubmit_Click" />
```

Here I gave a common validation group to textboxes(on which i wanted to fire a required field validation) and submit button. Hence all my validations will fire only on submit button.

The benefit of using this approach is all your work will be done client side and no need to take an extra headache of enabling and disabling the validations.

**Update**
Just use this code as it is.

```
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td>
            Book Name
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtbookname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Requires book name"
                ControlToValidate="txtbookname" ForeColor="Red" Text="*"  ValidationGroup="avail"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Book Availability" OnClick="btnavail_Click"  ValidationGroup="avail"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblbookavail" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Student Id
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtstudentid" runat="server" ValidationGroup="save"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator4" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Requires Studentid"
                ControlToValidate="txtstudentid" ForeColor="Red" Text="*"  ValidationGroup="save"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            No of Book
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtnoofbook" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator5" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Requires no of book"
                ControlToValidate="txtnoofbook" ForeColor="Red" Text="*"  ValidationGroup="save"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Date of lending
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtdate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Password
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtpassword" TextMode="Password" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator6" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Requires Studentid"
                ControlToValidate="txtpassword" ForeColor="Red" Text="*"  ValidationGroup="save"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:Label ID="lblpassword" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:Label>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Submit" 
                OnClick="btnsubmit_Click"  ValidationGroup="save" style="height: 26px"/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: If I want TextBox1 Validation group for btnavail and TextBox2 Validation group for btnsubmit,then what I want to do?

Comment: so for that you can create two diferent validation groups one for submit button and another for avail button

Comment: In my case you don't have to use causes validation or any other thing in your code behind like neabling and disabling validation just use validation group.

Comment: @MonaVaradharaju used your code and updated the answer.. use the code of updated answer